# Create nuget package and installing issues

Tags: installation, package, nuget

I created a nuget package, all seems to be ok (no error message), when I install it from Package Manager Console, the dll is in XXX/lib/lib ... I don't know why there are two lib folder ??? I tried to change my nuspec  with several solutions  but I always had the same folder

```
<package>
  <metadata>
    <id>Telerik.Reporting.OpenXmlRendering</id>
    <version>8.1.14.804</version>
    <title>Telerik.Reporting.OpenXmlRendering</title>
    <authors>XXXXX</authors>
    <owners>XXXXX</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Assembly XXXX</description>
    <copyright>Copyright XXXX</copyright>
    <references></references>
    <tags></tags>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="*.dll" target=".\" />
  </files>
</package>
```

I tried

```
 <file src="*.dll" target="lib\net45" />
 <file src="*.dll" target="lib\" />
 <file src="*.dll" target="" />
```

And the installed always put the dll in :
C:\XXXXXX\packages\Telerik.Reporting.OpenXmlRendering.8.1.14.804\lib\lib

Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: How are you creating the NuGet package? Is it being cached somewhere else? Are you installing it from a local directory configured as a package source? What does it look like if you open it with NuGet Package Explorer or rename it to .zip and unzip it?

Comment: I'm using VS2015 with Package Manager console, I've created a *.ps1 like this :